# Multiple gmail emails - how do I make others see the one I want?

Tags: email, gmail

I've recently started at a new uni, and someone made a typo in my name! I was assured everything was fixed in their system except that my email still had the typo, but that was fine because I could just use the second email connected to the account.

So the dodgy email is [myname]@student.[myuni].edu and the email I want to use is [myinitials]@[myuni].edu

If I send an email from a third account to either of these addresses, they appear in the same inbox (on gmail). I'm not entirely sure how that works - I'm guessing there are two addresses hooked up to the same account.

However, when I send an email from my gmail account to someone else, they see the dodgy email address showing the typo in my name.

Can one email account have multiple email addresses linked to it (as I assume is happening here) and if so, how can I change the default address so I can forget about the dodgy one forever?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Can one email account have multiple email addresses linked to it (as I assume is happening here)?**

Yes it can, typically called an email alias. Whether this is the case or not, we can't know for sure, on your system administrator can.

**...and if so, how can I change the default address so I can forget about the dodgy one forever?**

You don't, the system administrator does.